# qla2xxx - SNS scan failed

Tags: storage, proxmox, multipath

We have two hypervisor(Dell PowerEdge R630, virtualization environment: Proxmox), they are connected with an FC-switch and the FC-switch with the storage(dell compellent).
One of the hypervisor are connected via multipath to the storage and it's works.
The other hypervisor doesn't found the storage.

The not-finder-hypervisor says:

```
kernel: qla2xxx [0000:81:00.0]-001d: : Found an ISP2532 irq 93 iobase 0x00000000bf40f73b.
kernel: scsi host13: qla2xxx
kernel: qla2xxx [0000:81:00.0]-500a:13: LOOP UP detected (8 Gbps).
kernel: qla2xxx [0000:81:00.0]-00fb:13: QLogic QLE2562 - PCI-Express Dual Channel 8Gb Fibre Channel HBA.
kernel: qla2xxx [0000:81:00.0]-00fc:13: ISP2532: PCIe (5.0GT/s x8) @ 0000:81:00.0 hdma+ host#=13 fw=8.07.00 (90d5).
kernel: qla2xxx [0000:81:00.0]-209e:13: SNS scan failed -- assuming zero-entry result.
```

The multipath module is loaded into kernel. Both hypervisor have the same loaded modules.

```
dm_multipath           28672  1 dm_round_robin
```

Comment: Consider adding what the goal is and any other needed information. Hardware setup/configs. Loaded kernel modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check SAN-zoning and LUN-secuty on the array: they must define and allow host-connection with the array and LUNs on it.